# is there a way to leave notificationManager and alarmManger alive even when the app is closed?

Tags: java, android

how would you recommend for me to design an android app where i want it to

1) send location update every 10 minutes

2) to show push notification

I want both actions be available even when the app is closed.

Here i might ask for your explanation what "closed" states an app can be in?

a) removed from recent tasks stack - close the whole process including its services ?

b) forces closed - close the whole process including its services ?

c) other?

I was using

1) alarm manager that sends a pending intent to a broadcast receiver.

2) notification manager

I have tried to register all manager using ApplicationContext instead of Current-Activity context. Now both actions work even after user remove the app from the "recent tasks" stack.

but I'm not sure about the "closed" states so I might be missing something.

Comment: In the future please refrain from [posting the same question across StackExchange sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608387/is-there-a-way-to-leave-notificationmanager-and-alarmmanger-alive-even-when-the).  If you feel you have posted in the wrong place then flag for a moderator and we will look into migrating the question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but:

If you register a `PendingIntent`to the `AlarmManager` you can rely on the system to deliver your intent.

If you registered the `BroadcastReciever` *in your app's Manifest*, the code in the Receiver will be executed (Note: always consider doing the actual logic in an `IntentService`, since `BraodcastReceiver`s only have about 5 seconds to perform their work!).
Simply put your call to the `NotificationManager` here.

If you registered the `LocationListener` using the `ApplicationContext` it will receive the location updates until the user "force closes" your app. But you could schedule another Alarm that registers the LocationListener again.

But keep in mind that you should keep the location updates on a moderate level - it drains battery.

As for your question about the "closed" states:

1. **An app is not running**. It was never started, force closed by the user or crashed.
2. **The app is not visible.** The UI is "closed" but the process is still running. This happens if someone hits the back button and the app closes. The system might close it completely if it needs the memory (point 1).

There are probably more cases, but these are the usual ones.

If the AlarmManager calls to your BroadcastReceiver and the Type is RTC_WAKEUP your App will be started if it was closed before.

Comment: what "closed" states an app can be in

Comment: @user23621 see my edited answer.

Comment: BraodcastReceivers only have about 5 seconds to perform their work! - why is that?

Comment: If you registered the BroadcastReciever in your app's Manifest, the code in the Receiver will be executed - but then I saw force closing is stopping the whole process and thus the receiver as well

Comment: always consider doing the actual logic in an IntentService - but then it means I'll have to re-start a service every time? nowadays my reciever calls a regular java class (manager). no service

Comment: @user23621 Yes, that's whats intentservice is made for

Comment: thanks for your reply. what's missing in using regular manager in java class? can you please relate my 3 comments?

Comment: @user23621 that's just not how you do it. I think you should read a little more about Receivers, Services and the Application lifecycle in the docs. http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html